# ASP.Net - LinkButton - Update THEN Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an update button in editmode that fires a value back to the database.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
```

This works fine in updating the database from my EditItemTemplate.

I'd like it to update the db, then fire another event (change to a different URL)

I've tried this a few ways such as adding in to the above code such as

```
 OnClick="UpdateButton_BackToMyCustomers"
```

and code behind

```
 protected void UpdateButton_BackToMyCustomers(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("MyCustomers.aspx");
    }
```

but everything I've tried including the above method overrides the actual update and goes straight to my UpdateButton_BackToMyCustomers..

Is there a way to make the update, then have an event fire as above?

Comment: Why do you need to fire another event? Can't you just call `Response.Redirect("MyCustomers.aspx");` or whatever else you might want to do in your Command event handler.

Comment: How do I call response.redirect AFTER it has updated the database? If I use OnClick, it ignores the actual DB update and goes straight to the response.redirect !

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, just add a line of code after the code that updates the database, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's an update button in a edititemtemplate in a form view so it doesn't have code behind displayed.. I'm too rubbish at c# to know the code behind for that update so was hoping there might be something simpler like firing an event after the update